# how to display a column twice related by two IDs

Tags: sql-server

[image: Database Tables with Data]

Dear All,

Could you please give a hint to solve the following riddle. EmpID in EmpDetails table is related to issuedtoid and issuedbyid in stockrelease table. How to display the employee names for both issuedtoid and issuedbyid?

Sorry i couldn't describe you the problem completely. Database is sql server 2016 developer edition.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that EmpDetails.EmpID is unique:

```
select
  sr.ID,
  sr.StockID,
  sr.StockName,
  sr.TypeID,
  issuedto.EmpName as IssuedToEmpName,
  issuedby.EmpName as IssuedByEmpName,
  sr.StockOutQuantity,
  sr.Date,
  sr.Remarks
from StockRelease sr
left join EmpDetails issuedto on sr.IssuedToID = issuedto.EmpID
left join EmpDetails issuedby on sr.IssuedByID = issuedby.EmpID
```

Comment: dear sir ... thank for your reply ... yeah EmpDetails.EmpID is unique ... it gives an error as ... Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'to'.

Comment: I've corrected my answer to not use a reserved keyword as a table alias and to correctly reference the IssuedByID field in the second join - it should work fine now I believe.

Answer (score -1):

I corrected [3N1GM4's script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45956974/68587) and it worked.

```
SELECT sr.StockID, sr.StockName, sr.TypeID, 
       to1.EmpName AS IssuedTo, by1.EmpName AS IssuedBy, 
       sr.StockOutQuantity, sr.Date, sr.Remarks, by1.Designation
FROM StockRelease AS sr 
   LEFT JOIN EmpDetails AS to1 ON sr.IssuedToID = to1.EmpID
   LEFT JOIN EmpDetails AS by1 ON sr.IssuedByID = by1.EmpID
```

Comment: Yes, you're quite right, I used a keyword as a table alias and forgot to change the joining field in the second join when I copy/pasted it from the first one - my fault for not actually running my query to check it first! I have corrected my answer to reflect this - please feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.